# How to split a variable by a special character

Tags: awk

I have value which stores the present resolution, such as: **$2 = 1920x1080**. I would like to split the value based on the `x` character and store the result in 2 variables.  With the example above, the first variable will store 1920 and the second 1080.  I would then like to make the definition for a print command based on these two valyues.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
awk '{
   res=$2
   split(res,resArr,"x")
   print "resX=" resArr[1] "\tresY="resArr[2]
}' inFile
```

If I understand your needs correctly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Adama : Glad that helped and thanks for the upvote. If you need further help with your `awk,split` question, you can always post a new question. Be sure to include sample input, expected output from that sample, your current code, output and error messages along with your thoughts about why it is not working. Good luck!

Answer (score 26):

Depends on if I interpret you needs correctly...

**Interpretation 1**, string is "1920x1080"

```
echo 1920x1080 | awk -F"x" '{print $1, $2}'
1920 1080
```

**Interpretation 2**, string is "$2 = 1920x1080"

```
$ echo '$2 = 1920x1080' | awk -F"x" 'sub(/\$[0-9] += +/, "", $1){print $1, $2}'
1920 1080
```

In both examples, the width is placed in `$1` and the height in `$2`

Answer (score 4):

Using the shell parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/sh

res=1920x1080

res_x=${res%%x*}
res_y=${res##*x}

echo $res_x
echo $res_y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res='$2 = 1900x1080'
IFS=x
set -- $(egrep -o '[0-9]+x[0-9]+' <<< "$res")
res_x=$1
res_y=$2
```